# Perform action at the end of animation

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I've write an Animation for make text of a TextView blink, and i would perform an action after animation ends.
It's possible to intercept end of animation in some way?

Comment: you can use animation listener

Comment: apply animation listener on the animation whose you want to keep track of. `onAnimationEnd` will be called when animation ends and you can do your stuff in this method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AnimationListener listener = new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } 

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
};
```